# what is difference between nuget.org and api.nuget.org

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

we are using VS 2015 and managed our references through nugget package manager. We used to get reference of nugget from http://nuget.org in previous version of nugget manager. But in the latest edition, we see it is referred to  api.nuget.org instead of nugget.org. Is there any difference between these two version of nugget.org and api.nugget.org.

Answer (score 3):

api.nuget.org is the new API for NuGet version 3. This is REST based and uses JSON-LD.

nuget.org is the API for NuGet version 2. This is an odata based API.

There is some information in the [release notes for NuGet 3.0 beta](https://docs.nuget.org/release-notes/nuget-3.0-beta):

> In the NuGet 3.0 Beta bits, you'll see a new package source called "api.nuget.org" in the package source dropdown. If you select that package source, we'll use our new API rather to connect to nuget.org. In NuGet 3.0 RC, this new API v3-based package source will replace the v2-based "nuget.org" package source. We recommend disabling all of the other public package sources and leave only api.nuget.org as your only public package repository.